# CSS: Limit width of text background in position: absolute div?

Tags: html, css

I have some text I want to center in the middle of a `div`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">
            this is some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to position several background images behind this text, so I have set the `div` wrapping the text to `position:absolute`.

```
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

I also want that text to have padding and a background colour.

```
.text {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

However, the text's background stretches the entire length of the container `div`.
Is there some way to centre the `.text` and set its width to be only as long as the text is?

The only way I can do it currently is to remove the width of `.inner` and manually set a `margin-left` for `.text`, but my content is dynamic, so this won't work in the long term.

[JSFiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3Ahs2/8/)

Comment: There is no text in your fiddle!

Comment: Dog, I'm struggling a bit to understand what you want to achieve and fiddler doesn't offer any hint whatsoever, can you please be a bit more precise?

Comment: … and no absolute positioning either, only a width and background for the container div (and a syntactically faulty `height`). Try again …

Comment: you can try this maybe http://jsfiddle.net/3Ahs2/5/

Comment: @Leo damn! sorry I forgot to hit update on my fiddle. It should be ok now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **display: inline-block;** to the inner text div

eg:

```
.text {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

http://fiddle.jshell.net/R7ah9/

Answer (score 0):

If you add display:inline; to the .text style you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3Ahs2/1/

You need style text align center

Answer (score 0):

Test this code:

```
 .container {
      background-color: #FD5361;
      border: 1px solid #FF0000;
      height: 39px;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
     }
   .inner {
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 0.1;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        width: 300px;
     }
    .text {
       background-color: #000000;
       color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px 20px;
     }
    //such as background-position
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `height` property was missing a colon and I removed the possibly unnecessary `.inner` element.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ahs2/5/